# Dynamically add posts with there Post ID

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

In my wordpress website i am trying to add Posts with there `post_id`. The problem is that its add same post id for all the link which i add dynamically.

**Jquery:**

```
  $(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function(){     
  var post_title = $(this).closest('div').find('a').text();

  if( $('#post-container li').length <= 3 )
    $('#post-container').append( '<li id="<?php the_ID();?>"> '+ post_title + ' -- <a href="#" class="remove-title">REMOVE</a></li>' );   
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove-title', function(){
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });

 });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<?php 
    if( have_posts() ):             
     while( have_posts() ): the_post();                 
       <button  class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail  ( 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?> </a> 
    endwhile;
    endif; 
    wp_reset_query();
 ?>

<div id="post-container">   </div>
```

Using add button i successfully add post to div `id=post-container`. But This code add same id for all the link which i add to div `post-container`.

**How to add relative post_id to link with jquery?**

Comment: Are you getting different titles and content but the same ID?

Comment: yes,, problem is same ID for all different titles

Comment: @TonyM yes. problem is same as you mention

Comment: It is not clear whether `<?php the_ID();?>` is part of a loop which would get each ID. As it looks now, only 1 ID will be shown. The jQuery around it doesn't matter since it is executed after the PHP. If you don't need the exact Post ID, then you can use the Post title as ID like: `'<li id="'+post_title+'"> '`  Otherwise provide more context on how you're looping posts

Comment: in simple wordpress loop i use this tag '<button  class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>'  and its work for me. Now where and how i can use post title instead of this.

Comment: @TonyM i also update HTML part of Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 $('#post-container').append( '<li id="<?php the_ID();?>"> '+ post_title + ' -- <a href="#" class="remove-title">REMOVE</a></li>' );
```

To this:

```
$('#post-container').append( '<li id="'+post_title.toLowerCase()+'"> '+ post_title + ' -- <a href="#" class="remove-title">REMOVE</a></li>' );
```

This will set the post title, in lower case, as the ID

**Update:**

I see you've updated the info. I definitely would grab the ID from the loop.

Comment: Thanks.. And please some thing about to add post_thumbnail to view with title.

Comment: @Farooq what do you mean?

Comment: i also need to add thumbnail Dynamically like that.... `$('#post-container').append( '<li id="'+post_title.toLowerCase()+'"> '+post_thumbnail+' , '+ post_title + ' -- <a href="#" class="remove-title">REMOVE</a></li>' );`

Comment: Do you mean adding it as an image? Add the img tag to the above (as you normally would) and we can pull the thumbnail into the src.